# AWS IAM Authentication to MySQL from dotnet core code running in Lambda

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, connection-string

I have a lambda function written in dotnet core 2.1. This code uses the Oracle MySql provider (v8.0.19).  A MySQL RDS (v5.7.26) is running with a user configured to use the AWSAuthenticationPlugin as described in the AWS article linked below.

I'm able to connect to this RDS using a normal username/password combination, but I want to use IAM Authentication instead.  This article describes how to do this using the mysql client on a linux server: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html

I've created the IAM policy and I'm able to load the token in the lambda function via RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken.  The connection string is built as follows:

```
MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection();
MySqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new MySqlConnectionStringBuilder();
csb.Server = "dbinstanceName.xxx.us-xxx-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
csb.Port = 3306;
csb.Database = "Database";
csb.UserID = "DatabaseUserName";
csb.Password = RDSAuthTokenGenerator.GenerateAuthToken("dbinstanceName.xxx.us-xxx-1.rds.amazonaws.com", 3306, "DatabaseUserName");
csb.SslMode = MySqlSslMode.VerifyFull;
c.ConnectionString = csb.ConnectionString;
```

When I pass this token as the value for password in the connection string, I get the exception:

> "errorType": "MySqlException", 
>   "errorMessage": "Authentication method 'mysql_clear_password' not supported by any of the available plugins."

This MySQL article describes Client-Side cleartext pluggable Authentication (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cleartext-pluggable-authentication.html), however I don't know how to enable this plugin in the MySQL provider in dotnet.

Can anyone suggest a way to send this RDS Token in the connection string in clear text in dotnet core?  I can't seem to figure out how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make this work using a different MySQL provider.  If you are stuck, try using the MySqlConnector provider instead:

https://mysqlconnector.net/

With this provider, I did not have to change anything about the code/connection string above.

Hope this is helpful for someone else.